# Zarr slow read speed of 43.82 GB file with Xarray

Tags: data-science, netcdf, python-xarray, grib, zarr

I want to look-up 8760 times for a single lat/lon combo in **less than a second** from 43.82 GB file of wind data containing:

- 8760 times (every hour in a year)
- 721 latitudes (every 0.25° from -90.0° to 90.0°)
- 1440 longitude (every 0.25° from -180.0° to 179.75°)

[image]

The best time we achieved for a single-year look-up was 16 seconds for both u100 and v100 wind speed at 100m vectors. We want to have a **sub-second look-up** for the whole year as such file read will need to happen on **every user request** in our API.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()

    ds = xr.open_dataset("2021.zarr", engine="zarr", chunks={"time": 50})

    print(f"Took {round((time.time() - start_time) * 1000, 2)}ms")

    location = ds.sel(indexers={"latitude": 53.494, "longitude": 9.979}, method='nearest')

    wind_speed = (location.u100.values ** 2 + location.v100.values ** 2) ** 0.5

    print(f"Wind Speed: {wind_speed} m/s")
    print(f"Took {round((time.time() - start_time) * 1000, 2)}ms")
```

Output:

```
Took 94.28ms
Wind Speed: [5.8021994 5.504477  5.4270387 ... 9.563195  8.701231  9.133655 ] m/s
Took 16299.59ms
```

I would be very thankful for any help!

Comment: If you want to always look up the entire length of the time dimension, it should be in a single or low number of chunks. Adjust the chunking of the remaining dimensions to have a sensible overall chunks for data access pattern and chunksize for throughput

Comment: @Val Setting the time chunk as 8760 or removing it produces slower read speeds. Chunking by latitude or longitude does not have an effect on speeding up the look-up.

Comment: The important part is how your zarr file is chunked on disk. Changing the chunksize on read can slow down the read (as you need to re-chunk). But try to understand what takes the most time on your operation, and then you can optimize.

Comment: Presumably xarray is calculating nearest neighbour for every time step. Can you just calculate the i,j indices once and then select them instead of using sel as in the code given? That could speed things up

Comment: @RobertWilson Great idea! It probably sped up due to the exact lookup, but only by 10%. `ds.isel(indexers={"latitude": 0, "longitude": 0})` took 15508.96ms.

Comment: I don't work with zarr extensively, but I would be surprised if you could now make this 10 times faster, based on netCDF experience. Restructuring the data itself could do it, maybe...

Comment: ... as it has been already commented, you need to re-chunk your data on disk. What is the actual chunking on-disk of the data?